# Zooming on y axises using amchart

Tags: amcharts

I use AmSerialChart. On the x (date) axis I can zoom in and out and I can pan my trend to the left, to the right. I use more than 2 Y axises: [see here](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/) Is it possible to zoom in and out for every y axises individually?
Can I change the computed yMin and yMax scales anyway? I cannot find any method or possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

individually is not possible, it adapts itself automatically to the current selection (viewable area) set the `minimum` and `maximum` on the [valueAxis](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis)